# Trying to convert morse code to english. struggling

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function to read Morse code from one file, convert it to English text, print the converted text to the terminal, and write it to an output file. Here's a rough start...
`#define TOTAL_MORSE 91`
`#define MORSE_LEN 6`

```
void 
morse_to_english(FILE* inputFile, FILE* outputFile, char morseStrings[TOTAL_MORSE][MORSE_LEN])
{ int i = 0, compare = 0;
 char convert[MORSE_LEN] = {'\0'}, *buffer = '\0';
 //read in a line of morse string from file
// fgets(buffer, //then what?
 while(((convert[i] = fgetc(inputFile)) != ' ') && (i < (MORSE_LEN - 1)))
 { i++;
 }
 if (convert[i + 1] == ' ')
  convert[i + 1] = '\0';
 //compare read-in string w/morseStrings
 for (i = 48, compare = strcmp(convert, morseStrings[i]); //48 is '0'
  i < (TOTAL_MORSE - 1) && compare != 0;
  i++) 
 { compare = strcmp(convert, morseStrings[i]);
 }
 printf("%c", (char)i);
}
```

I have initialized morseStrings to the morse code. 
That's my function right now. It does  not work, and I'm not really sure what approach to take.

My original algorithm plan was something like this:
`1. Scan Morse code in from file, character by character, until a space is reached`
     `1.1 save to a temporary buffer (convert)`
`2. loop while i < 91 && compare != 0`

```
    compare = strcmp(convert, morseString[i])
```

`3. if (test ==0) print ("%c", i);`
`4. loop through this until eof`

but.. I can't seem to think of a good way to test if the next char in the file is a space. So this has made it very difficult for me.

I got pretty frustrated and googled for ideas, and found a suggestion to use this algorithm

1. Read a line
2. Loop

   -strchr() for a SPACE or EOL
   -copy characters before the space to another string
   -Use strcmp() and loop to find the letter
   -Test the next character for SPACE.
   -If so, output another space
   -Skip to next morse character
3. List item

Endloop

But, this loops is kind of confusing. I would use fgets() (I think), but I don't know what to put in the length argument.

Anyways, I'm tired and frustrated. I would appreciate any help or insight for this problem. I can provide more code if necessary.

Comment: I think you mean ASCII, not English. Converting Morse code to English could be very difficult if the original message is in French, for example. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original plan looks fine. You're off by 1 when you check for the `' '` in the buffer, though. It's at `convert[i]`, not `convert[i + 1]`. The `i++` inside the loop doesn't happen when a space is detected.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The char I was printing was off by one also, but that was easily fixed. I just got really frustrated, I think, with file-scanning strategies that weren't working, that I assumed there was a larger problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use strchr(), to complicated.

1. Loop through the Inputfile reading a line
2. tokenize line with [strtok][1]
3. loop through tokens and save(best append) the single Letters to a Buffer
4. close looops and print

a bit of pseudocode for u

```
while(there is a next line){

tokens = strtok(line);
int i = 0;

while(tokens hasnext){
save to buffer}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the CPU time you can write a lookup table to find the values, something as a switch like this:

```
case '.-': code =  "A";  break;
case '-...': code =  "B";  break;
case '-.-.': code =  "C";  break;
```

After you split the morse code by the spaces and send the diferent . and - combinations to the switch to get the original character.

I hope this help.
Best regards.

Comment: Interesting idea. Aren't `switch` statement limited to ten cases though?

Comment: @SubniC, you can only switch on integral values (including single characters), not strings. Additionally, the code you've given doesn't compile because you've put strings inside single quotes, when single quotes are for characters.

Comment: @Martin: this is not strictly correct - gcc allows you to define integer constants using up to 4 chars, e.g. `const int x = 'abcd';` and you can also use such constants as case labels, e.g. `case 'ABCD':`. The morse alphabet only uses 4 elements for alphabetic characters, so the above suggestion from SubniC would work for A-Z, but unfortunately you need 5 for numbers and more for punctuation etc.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can have at least 256 cases in a switch according to the standard.

Comment: Accorfing to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n897.pdf you can have 257 case statements in a switch, 1023 if you use C99.

Comment: Didn't know that. The book I'm studying (Problem Solving and Program Design in C, by Hanly and Koffman) said to not to make switch statements to larger than ten cases. I wonder why that would be.

Comment: You both are right @Martin and @Paul, sorry, i had a morse app but it did the oposite, get the morse from the characters so the switch is ok there. I think the 10 cases is because of the Ciclomatic complexity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity regards.