# Parsing string and using result to search a map for correct value

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am new to maps and a map seemed like a good idea for this problem. I want to provide an input and run that input through a map and then output the associated values. Is it possible to do something along these lines?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
std::string word;
word ="1110001010101000100000001110111010111000101011100010100011101011101000111010111";
//std::cout << "Please, enter your phrase: ";
//std::getline (std::cin,word);


// char inputstring[100];
//while(std::cin.good()){

std::map <std::string, char> morse_char;
morse_char["000"] = ' ';
morse_char["10111"] = 'a';
morse_char["111010101"] = 'b';
morse_char["11101011101"] = 'c';
morse_char["1110101"] = 'd';
morse_char["1"] = 'e';
morse_char["101011101"] = 'f';
morse_char["111011101"] = 'g';
morse_char["1010101"] = 'h';
morse_char["101"] = 'i';
morse_char["1011101110111"] = 'j';
morse_char["111010111"] = 'k';
morse_char["101110101"] = 'l';
morse_char["1110111"] = 'm';
morse_char["11101"] = 'n';
morse_char["11101110111"] = 'o';
morse_char["10111011101"] = 'p';
morse_char["1110111010111"] = 'q';
morse_char["1011101"] = 'r';
morse_char["10101"] = 's';
morse_char["111"] = 't';
morse_char["1010111"] = 'u';
morse_char["101010111"] = 'v';
morse_char["1110111"] = 'w';
morse_char["11101010111"] = 'x';
morse_char["1110101110111"] = 'y';
morse_char["11101110101"] = 'z';



//}
std::cout << word << std::endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you have it backwards, you lookup the key, output the value.

Comment: Yes I mixed them up when writing the question; I'd like to take that input and using the keys output the appropriate values instead of using something like a bunch of switch statements.

Comment: Your problem seems to not be how to use the map, but how to split `word` up into segments of morse code reprepsenting individual characters so they can be looked up in the map.

Comment: Yes, what I'd like to to take in the whole word and then apply the key values to it, so it would iterate through every key until for instance the key representing t was hit because only this key would work first. After finding an appropriate we would start the iteration over.

Comment: As soon as you start iterating to look up a value, a map (or any other associative container) is no longer what you want, although you can make do with them. Is this homework?

Comment: It's not homework it's this problem: http://www.csupomona.edu/~carich/programming_contests/200904/demorse.pdf

Comment: The basis of this is just really trying to use a map instead of a bunch of switch statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the kind of solution I was looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

 std::vector<std::string> split( const std::string& code, const std::string& sep )
 {
    std::vector<std::string> result ;

    std::string::size_type pos = 0 ;
    auto f = code.find(sep) ;
    while( f != std::string::npos )
    {
        result.emplace_back( code.begin()+pos, code.begin()+f ) ;
        pos = f + sep.size() ;
        f = code.find( sep, pos ) ;
    }
    result.push_back( code.substr(pos) ) ;

    return result ;
 }

 int main()
 {
    typedef std::map <std::string, char> morse_charT;
    morse_charT my_morse;
    my_morse["000"] = ' ';
    my_morse["10111"] = 'a';
    my_morse["111010101"] = 'b';
    my_morse["11101011101"] = 'c';
    my_morse["1110101"] = 'd';
    my_morse["1"] = 'e';
    my_morse["101011101"] = 'f';
    my_morse["111011101"] = 'g';
    my_morse["1010101"] = 'h';
    my_morse["101"] = 'i';
    my_morse["1011101110111"] = 'j';
    my_morse["111010111"] = 'k';
    my_morse["101110101"] = 'l';
    my_morse["1110111"] = 'm';
    my_morse["11101"] = 'n';
    my_morse["11101110111"] = 'o';
    my_morse["10111011101"] = 'p';
    my_morse["1110111010111"] = 'q';
    my_morse["1011101"] = 'r';
    my_morse["10101"] = 's';
    my_morse["111"] = 't';
    my_morse["1010111"] = 'u';
    my_morse["101010111"] = 'v';
    my_morse["1110111"] = 'w';
    my_morse["11101010111"] = 'x';
    my_morse["1110101110111"] = 'y';
    my_morse["11101110101"] = 'z';

    const std::string word_seperator = "0000000" ;
    const std::string letter_seperator = "000" ;

    const std::string msg =    
"1110001010101000100000001110111010111000101011100010100011101011101000111010111" ;

    for( const std::string& word : split( msg, word_seperator ) )
    {

        for( const std::string& letter : split( word, letter_seperator ) )
        {

            morse_charT::iterator  it= my_morse.find(letter);
            if( it != my_morse.end() ) std::cout  << it->second;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look the the source in this question

[Trying to convert morse code to english. struggling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192345/trying-to-convert-morse-code-to-english-struggling)

the basic idea is that you compare your `word` with each morse code and find a match.

Comment: The segments of morse code will need to be sorted from longest to shortest tho i suspect? because some of the longer sequences are prefixed with shorter sequences. i know nothing about morse code tho ;)